# 継承されたコントロールに継承されたスタイルを使う

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

`CustomToggleButton`は`ToggleButton`を継承しています：

```
class CustomToggleButton : ToggleButton {

    static CustomToggleButton() {
        CustomToggleButton.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(CustomToggleButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomToggleButton)));
    }

    // 省略   
}
```

`ToggleButtonCommon`は`CustomToggleButton`用基本設定のスタイルであり、`InGroupToggleButton`スタイルは`ToggleButtonCommon`を継承しています：

```
<Style  x:Key="ToggleButtonCommon"
        TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomToggleButton}" 
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">

        // 省略
</Style>

<Style x:Key="InGroupToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource ToggleButtonCommon}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="5 5 5 0" />
</Style>
```

上記ですと、`ToggleButtonCommon`スタイルを利用できますが、`InGroupToggleButton`は利用できません：

```
<local:CustomToggleButton Style="{StaticResource InGroupToggleButton}"/>
```

警告メッセージ：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どうしても`InGroupToggleButton`を使いたいなら、手がありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <Style x:Key="InGroupToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource ToggleButtonCommon}">
>     <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="5 5 5 0" />
> </Style>
> ```

ここに`TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomToggleButton}"`を指定する必要があります。

Comment: 異常ありません！ご解決、誠にありがとうございます！